# VirtualHost doesnt seem to be working

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, coldfusion

Good morning.
I recently migrated my web server to new hardware and to the newest version of Apache. I was running Apache 2 before as well just to be clear.
I seem to be having problems getting my `virtualhost` to work properly. On the old server, I only had 1 `virtualhost` set up and it was for `/var/ww/prism`. When I moved everything to the new server, I could hit the prism site, but unfortunately everywhere you tried to navigate within `/var/www` would fail because it was trying to look within the prism site. I discovered through documentation that adding the `_default_:*` virtualhost should clear it up. Thankfully this did allow me to get to all of the other sites directly via IP, but unfortunately now my prism virtualhost doesnt navigate when I put in the URL. Does anyone see any obvious misconfigurations in my httpd.conf?

```
<Directory /var/www/employment_applicant_tracking/secure/pdf/>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1, localhost
Allow from 172.16.0.0/20
Options none
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/cfide/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from 172.16.0.0/20
Allow from 127
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/CFIDE/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from 172.16.0.0/20
Allow from 127
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
ErrorDocument 400 /error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ErrorDocument 405 /error.html
ErrorDocument 406 /error.html
ErrorDocument 407 /error.html
ErrorDocument 408 /error.html
ErrorDocument 409 /error.html
ErrorDocument 410 /error.html
ErrorDocument 411 /error.html
ErrorDocument 412 /error.html
ErrorDocument 413 /error.html
ErrorDocument 414 /error.html
ErrorDocument 415 /error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html
ErrorDocument 501 /error.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error.html
ErrorDocument 504 /error.html
ErrorDocument 505 /error.html
</Directory>
NameVirtualHost 172.16.0.13:80

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.16.0.13:80>
ServerName requests.mydomain.com
ServerPath /prism/
DocumentRoot /var/www/prism
</VirtualHost>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.cfm
# JRun Settings
LoadModule jrun_module /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so
<IfModule mod_jrun22.c>
    JRunConfig Verbose false
    JRunConfig Apialloc false
    JRunConfig Ignoresuffixmap false
    JRunConfig Serverstore /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/jrunserver.store
    JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:51800
    #JRunConfig Errorurl url <optionally redirect to this URL on errors>
    #JRunConfig ProxyRetryInterval 600 <number of seconds to wait before trying to reconnect to unreachable clustered server>
    #JRunConfig ConnectTimeout 15 <number of seconds to wait on a socket connect to a jrun server>
    #JRunConfig RecvTimeout 300 <number of seconds to wait on a socket receive to a jrun server>
    #JRunConfig SendTimeout 15 <number of seconds to wait on a socket send to a jrun server>
    AddHandler jrun-handler .jsp .jws .cfm .cfml .cfc .cfr .cfswf
</IfModule>
<Files ~ ".hbmxml$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: **bah** I was able to resolve the issue. forgot my entry in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to put an entry in /etc/hosts

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.